# split params into array elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have parameters being passed into my update action that I would like to convert into an array of integers like [1, 2, 3] currently the array has one string element ["1, 2, 3"].  I thought I would be able to just take the "1, 2, 3" from the params and split them into an array of ["1", "2", "3"] to then convert into the array of integers.

```
arr = article_params[:allowed_organization_ids]
arr_split = arr.split(",").map(&:to_i)
Rails.logger.debug(arr_split.inspect)

#<NoMethodError: undefined method `to_i' for ["4,2"]:Array>
```

if I try just splitting the string it doesn't work i get an extra set of brackets wrapped around the original array like this `[["1,2,3"]]`

```
arr = article_params[:allowed_organization_ids]
arr_split = arr.split(",")
Rails.logger.debug(arr_split.inspect)
```

Parameters:

```
  Processing by ArticlesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"j+2xEqGf9ECwjgfGHGdaXwiL09klNGYE12fdfdfdfdfdfn47e8abcuukp9sL5ZzMw==", 
"article"=>{"title"=>"test1", "subtitle"=>";ji", 
"product_line_id"=>"3", "is_highlighted"=>"0", "is_featured"=>"0",  "allowed_organization_ids"=>["4,2"]}, "id"=>"168"}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, [see here](https://rextester.com/ZPKJW3727).

Comment: can you show your params that you are getting this issue with ?

Comment: just added my params.  thanks

Comment: I think you should check `params` for all conditions or cases.. also it it will be better to use `pry` gem to work with such cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a nested array just call `first`...

```
arr_split = arr.first.split(",").map(&:to_i)
```

Answer (score 1):

If an array like arr =  ["1, 2, 3", "4, 5, 6"]
then use following thing:

```
arr =  ["1, 2, 3", "4, 5, 6"]
converted_array = arr.join(",").split(",").collect {|i| i.to_i}
```